# Walter rudin 9.32

Tags: analysis, derivatives, metric-spaces, matrix-rank, projection

There are the theorem and its proof :

$\mathscr b'$ mapping means continuously differentiable function.

[image]

[image]

I don't understand how do we get (76) from (71).
If this is so then it means that ($PF(H(X))$)' = $P(F(H(X))'$
But from where we can say that this is true?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The derivative of a linear map $P$ is given by $P$ - just write down what it means, that a map is the derivative of $P$: it is a linear map $A$ such that $P h= Ah + o(|h|)$...Now apply the chain rule in (71).

Comment: (Of course the $Ph$ on the left hand side in my comment should be $P(x+h) - P(x)$, which reduces to $Ph$...)

Answer (score 2):

It will be the same as the derivative of $\frac d{dx}(Ax)$ and it's equal of $A.$